# Unsetting Case Priority field default value

Tags: case

Seems to be an easy process, but not sure where I'm stuck.

```
Error: Cannot uncheck this value. This picklist must have "Default" value.
```

I want to unset the default value of Case Priority field and set it to None this way users have to select a value. I have made sure the field is not required on any page layouts but it still won't let me know unset the default value. I have also created a validation rule that does not allow for Priority field to be blank which should act as required criteria for saving.

I have seen suggestions to create another -- None -- value in the picklist and set that as the default, but that seems kludgy and you end up with 2 --None-- values in the dropdown.

Any help is appreciated even if you think this field can't be without default value.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this answer on the other forums. In case it helps anyone else inf the future.

> Unfortunately, it is not possible in Salesforce at this moment. There
> is already an idea for this which you can upvote.
>
> https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdW05UAF/priority-default-not-required

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.